# Microsoft Identity 2 SignInManager never returns VerificationRequired

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, asp.net-identity-2, two-factor-authentication

I'm trying to add 2-factor authentication using pin codes sent in email. The 2FA step is only required by users 30 days after they last completed the 2FA step.

Project's tech is ASP.NET MVC 5 using EntityFramework 6 with NuGet package version 2.2.2 of the Microsoft.AspNet.Identity packages(.Core, .EntityFramework, .Owin).

I've been following the advice in this tutorial, but integrating it in my company's already existing solution: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/two-factor-authentication-using-sms-and-email-with-aspnet-identity

**My problems**

*SignInManager never returns RequiresVerification when using the PasswordSignIn*
I assumed that I should expect this login status, when the "TwoFactorEnabled" flag is set to true in the database for each user. I'm not sure if I should use this, if I only want users to go through the 2FA verification every 2 weeks, as it's my impression that it will require users to go through this every time. Either that, or I should use a timestamp set on the user to determine, if it's time to reenable the "TwoFactorEnabled" flag?

*I can't retrieve the verified user's ID, when verifying code*
I thought that after performing a normal PasswordSignIn, the server would be able to retrieve the user's ID, for example when verifying that the entered pin code is correct:

```
[HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> VerifyCode(string pin)
    {
        string userId = await SignInManager.GetVerifiedUserIdAsync().WithCurrentCulture();

        if (userId == null || String.IsNullOrEmpty(pin))
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        var user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        if (await UserManager.VerifyTwoFactorTokenAsync(user.Id, "EmailCode", pin))
        {
            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, false, false);
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Dashboards");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid code");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

It's a little bit confusing, since most tutorials are very old, and use the AuthenticationManager, which I have never seen before.

*How do I prevent users from simply skipping to other pages from the verification screen, if they're already "successfully logged in with username and password"*
Won't they be able to bypass the Authorization attribute at this point?

**What already works**
I can get the UserManager to send an email with a token(pin code), and it will be successfully verified, if I enter the correct user ID

**What I have done**
I have the standard/default Identity setup, so we're using the standard configuration pretty much that comes with new MVC 5 projects.

Startup.Auth:

```
// Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));

        // Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        // Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        // This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);
```

2FA provider setup in ApplicationUserManager:

```
        manager.RegisterTwoFactorProvider("EmailCode", new EmailTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>
        {
            Subject = "Security Code",
            BodyFormat = "Your security code is {0}"
        });

        manager.EmailService = new EmailService();
        //manager.SmsService = new SmsService();
        var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider =
                new DataProtectorTokenProvider<ApplicationUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }

        return manager;
```

Thank you very much in advance for any help.

Comment: Just to confirm:Are the cookies being set in your browser after 1st level of authenetication? if  application being run in development mode using google chrome you will have trouble in setting the cookies for the localhost domain. U need to have a registry controlled domain.This is a known security issue in chrome. try running on other browsers as well. Reference to the issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=56211

Comment: On the other hand you can set the SSL of the application to true in the proect properties and copy the https link to your web properties to circumvent the issue to be able to work in chrome

Comment: @bhanu.cs thanks for your answer. I just tried running in development mode with Firefox instead, but I still get a Success SignInStatus.

Comment: @bhanu.cs 

What I do right now is the following:

1. User sends username and password in AJAX Request to JsonResult method called login.

2. In this method, I perform a sign in with the SignInManager. I pass the SignInStatus plus the ApplicationUser to a method that switches on the SignInStatus.

Comment: 3. If SignInStatus is Success I now simply check a claim value on the user, which contains a date. If the date is older than 30 days, I send them a pin code and redirect to a VerifyCode page, where they have to enter the pin code. Also if this was the case, I do not set any session variables for user, but I have already performed a PasswordSignIn, which is probably problematic? I only set a single Session variable containing their UserId, which I fetch, when they submit their pin code.

Comment: 4. The user enters the code in the input text field, and I reperform the signin process, which now will pass the 2FA check and sets the session variables.

Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh I see,that is a clever workaround u had thought of. But in step 3 since the 2FA is enabled SignInManager returns RequireVerification status and the auth cookie would not be generated untill 2FA is done(I'm not sure of this although other intermediate cookies are generated) which would leave you not authenticated.Did you consider this case? In short if 2FA is enabled untill phone code or email code is provided you may not be authenticated.

Comment: @bhanu.cs hey, I have added an answer. I think it all came down to the EmailConfirmed flag being false as you said, which is why the RequiresVerification status wasn't returned(impossible to perform email authorization, if the email isn't correct). I wish they would instead have returned a 2FA method with a warning message saying it can't be used since the user hasn't confirmed their email. Thanks for your help and checking back in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I may have figured out what the problem is.
The UserManager returned 0 for GetValidTwoFactorProvidersAsync. It seems that this occurs, when the email isn't confirmed for the user. I tried settings email as confirmed for the user, and now RequiresVerification is returned.

When RequiresVerification is returned, it seems the user isn't completely signed in, but I'm still able to fetch the user ID in subsequent code verification calls using the SignInManager's GetVerifiedUserId method.

So now, when a user logs in, before performing the password sign-in, I simply perform a check to see, when the user last completed 2FA authentication. If it's been more than 30 days, I reenable the 2FA flag in the database. Then when the password signin is performed, I'll get RequiresVerification as expected, and I can continue the rest of the flow as any standard 2FA verification would otherwise require.